# UIScrollView stops working when label text in UIScrollView is changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have had this problem for a long time now, I hope stackoverflow can help!

THE PROBLEM IS

When I enter "Alan Shearer" into the EnterNameText (UI TEXTFIELD) the label changes text, however the ScrollView no longer scrolls to the set content size, it will scroll a little bit, but no were near the set content size, in this case 2000px in height.

details

1) Xcode 4.5.1

2) IOS 6

In my .xib file ( tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2h4yx3o&s=6 ) I have a UIScrollView (320 pixels in width, and 490 pixels in height) 
The UIScrollView contains labels that are all connected to view controller.h.

The Label (all labels are set in the same way) :

```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *AlanShearerLabel;
```

my UIScrollView in ViewController.h looks like this:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
```

UIScrollView in ViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{[super viewDidAppear:animated]; self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320.0, 2000.0);  }
```

An IBAction called - (IBAction)CheckButton:(id)sender

The action when CheckButton is clicked:

```
//string 0

NSString *string0 = _EnterNameText.text;

//Alan Shearer

NSString *string1 =@"Alan Shearer";
NSString *string2 =@"Rank 1) Alan Shearer 260 Goals";
NSString *stringshearer =@"Shearer";

//Alan Shearer IF

if([string0 isEqualToString:string1]||
   [string0 isEqualToString:stringshearer])
{_AlanShearerLabel.text = string2;
    _AlanShearerLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _EnterNameText.text=@"";

}
```

Comment: i think code is right, some thing else has a problem. Are u using any code to move the scrollview to top when keyboard covers the textField, if yes shows that code..

Comment: No I am not, the keyboard never covers the text field, it pops over the uiscrollview.

Comment: where is your check button, is this ur complete check button or some more is there.?

Comment: here is a link to the layout of my xib file http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2h4yx3o&s=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue you must be sure to define all the things inside the scrollview before you link the scrollview to the .h file.  For example if you have 20 labels in a scrollview, be sure that the 20 labels have been connected to the .h file, set the right size, put in the right place.  Only then do you connect your scrollview to the .h file and place the scrollview code in viewDidAppear rather then viewdidload.